# How can i directly acess embedded document object mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Here is my document

```
{
  "_id":"1000",
  "event_name":"Some name",  
  "tracks":
   [
     {
         "id":"100"
         "title":"Test title",
     },
     {
          "id":"101"
         "title":"Test title 2",
     }

  ]
}
```

I want to directly acess track with id 101

So far i am doing this

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("tracks.$._id").is(id));
// Execute the query and find one matching entry
Event event= mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Event.class,MongoDBCollections.EVENT);
```

I want some thing like this

Track track = event.getTrackById(id); how can i get track from that event object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the positional operator in the wrong place, it is a "projection" modifier and is not part of the query. You add the fields on the query spec with the [`.include()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Field.html#include(java.lang.String)) method:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("tracks._id").is(id);
query.fields().include("tracks.$");
Event event = mongoTemplate.findOne(query,Event.class,MongoDBCollections.EVENT);
```

But as with all projecton, the list of "fields" is all or nothing. So you either specify all of the fields to match your result class or modify that result class to just the fields you wish to return.

Comment: Thanks @Neil Lunn! That is working ! Can you suggest me how can i get specific track from that event?

Comment: @RamzanZafar The positional operator in the field projection only returns the first match from the array. So that is the specific track you asked for and only that array element. See the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/).